# TabBar won't rebuild after using animateTo

Tags: flutter

I'm using tabBar to differentiate between registered and unregistered user for my app. By default the active index is (0) and I wanted to detect if the user add someone that's unregistered it will change the tab index to (1).

I manage to do so but the problem is my UI wont be rebuild, I have to close my keyboard first or change between tab to see the changes. How to fix this ?

Here's my code:

```
  findUser(String phoneNumber, BuildContext context) async {
    /// Some logic Code

    if (status == 'Unregistered') {
          setState(() {
            selectedUnregisteredPhoneNumber.add('+62$phoneNumber');
            tabController.animateTo(1, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
          });
        }
  }
```

My code for UI:

```
  Widget buildUnregisteredPhoneNumberTab() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          if (selectedUnregisteredPhoneNumber.isNotEmpty)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: selectedUnregisteredPhoneNumber.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text('build the phone number');
                },
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `IndexedStack` to rebuild UI, UI should rebuilt automatically after animateTo. code:

```
class MyAwesomeTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAwesomeTabs({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAwesomeTabsState createState() => _MyAwesomeTabsState();
}

class _MyAwesomeTabsState extends State<MyAwesomeTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;

  List<String> selectedUnregisteredPhoneNumber = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: tabController,
          tabs: const [
            Tab(text: 'Registered'),
            Tab(text: 'Unregistered'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: tabController.index,
        children: [
          buildRegisteredPhoneNumberTab(),
          buildUnregisteredPhoneNumberTab(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void findUser(String phoneNumber) async {
    // Some logic Code

    if (status == 'Unregistered') {
      setState(() {
        selectedUnregisteredPhoneNumber.add('+62$phoneNumber');
        tabController.animateTo(1, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
      });
    }
  }

  Widget buildRegisteredPhoneNumberTab() {
    return const Center(child: Text('Registered Phone Numbers'));
  }

  Widget buildUnregisteredPhoneNumberTab() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          if (selectedUnregisteredPhoneNumber.isNotEmpty)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: selectedUnregisteredPhoneNumber.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text(selectedUnregisteredPhoneNumber[index]);
                },
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```